# Genetic programming from a specification language?

Tags: specifications, genetic-programming

I'm searching for papers which describe how to make a fitness function in genetic programming use a specification language such as z notation in order to evolve a program which matches the specification. Does anyone know of any relevant research or implementations?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post, this book is absolutely amazing:
http://www.rubyinside.com/clever-algorithms-a-free-book-of-nature-inspired-ruby-recipes-4227.html

its is online / for free as well.

have fun with it

Comment: In addition to [Genetic Programming](http://cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/evolution/genetic_programming.html), consider taking a look at automatic programming techniques such as [Gene Expression Programming](http://cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/evolution/gene_expression_programming.html) and [Grammatical Evolution](http://cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/evolution/grammatical_evolution.html). In addition to the general problem of representation, the cost function will include terms for things such as parsimony.